# Identification needed for this fast growing vine

Tags: identification, vines

This vine started growing around 6-8weeks ago its growing quite fast. So far its only a runner with leaves no suckers or stranglers. It look harmless to other plants its climbing on, since I just move it of.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the stems are rough with coarse short hairs it’s probably Japanese hops.

Answer (score 0):

Virginia Creeper and it is an invasive weed.  It is hard to get rid of, but perseverance finally does it in. When we moved here, it was twining through azalea bushes and it took three years to finally eliminate it.  Our backyard neighbor must think it is a ground cover and let it grow, including up the tall pines.  I have to spray weed killer on the darn ones that start to crawl between the fence.

Comment: Thanks for responding but the weed in question has no resemblance to a Virginia Creeper